# Independence of order of insertion hashtable with open addressing

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I'm taking a data-structure class, and the lecturer made the following assertion:

> the number of attempts needed to insert *n* keys in a hash table with [linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing) is independent of their order.

No proof was given, so I tried to get one myself. However, I'm stuck.

My approach at the moment: I try to show that if I swap two adjacent keys the number of attempts doesn't change. I get the idea behind it, and I think it's going in the right direction, but I can't manage to make it into a rigorous proof.

Aside, does this fact also hold for other probing techniques such as [quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing) or [double hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing)?

Comment: @EarlGrey, this seems a theoretical question. I don't see how any code should be involved? See [linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing)

Comment: No matter in what order you insert a bunch of keys into a hash table they will always occupy the same positions only their order changes. And for the keys to occupy those positions you have to get the same number of collisions, you could get a few collisions here and there or you could get a lot in the end, this depends on the order of insertion, but the number of collisions you get in the end still stays the same. No proof, but maybe you can do something with that.

Answer (score 0):

## Linear Probing

Here’s one way to see that the insertion order doesn’t matter for linear probing when counting the number of total slots touched.

For simplicity, let’s assume the linear probing table does not end up completely filled in, meaning that the final table configuration consists of a series of runs of elements separated by empty slots. Pick any one of those runs and focus on the elements in it. Again, for simplicity, let’s assume that the first slot in that run is slot 0, the next slot is slot 1, etc.

The main insight we’re going to use is the following. Rather than summing up the work done inserting the first element, then the second, etc., we’re going to sum up the amount of work done due to scanning over slot 0, then slot 1, then slot 2, etc., and we’re going to show that this amount is not impacted in any way by the order in which the elements are inserted.

Focus on slot 0. Suppose that k items have hash code 0. Regardless of the order in which we insert those items, we know that the first of those items to be inserted will get slot 0, and all the k-1 remaining items will, when inserted, scan over slot 0, see that it’s occupied, and then move to slot 1. Therefore, regardless of the insertion order of those k elements, we can treat it as though one item immediately gets the slot (requiring looking at slot 0 once), and then the remaining k-1 items look at slot 0 and, from that point forward, act as though they were *actually* inserted into slot 1. Therefore, we’re left with a situation where, regardless of order, we scan slot 0 a total of k times, then are left with a smaller collection of elements that are inserted into slots other than slot 0.

Now look at slot 1. There are some number of items that naturally hash here, plus k-1 items that would normally go in slot 0 but can’t because that slot is taken. Let’s suppose there’s r total items here. Regardless of the order in which items are inserted, one of these r items will be the first one inserted that gets slot 1. The other r-1 items will, when inserted, touch slot 1, see that it’s in use, and then act as though they were actually inserted into slot 2. Using similar reasoning to the above, this means that across all insertions, we’ll touch slot 1 a total of r times, and we’re now left with a collection of items to place that don’t use slots 0 or 1.

By repeating this argument across increasing slot numbers, we end up seeing that the number of times that *any* slot is touched is independent of the order in which items are inserted.

(More formally: we do this by induction. Suppose we have n elements to place in a table, and assume the very first slot and very last slot in the table is never filled. If n = 0, then we have no slots touched at all regardless of insertion order. Otherwise, suppose the claim works for any way of inserting any series of n items. Now suppose you insert n+1 items. Look at the k items that hash to the lowest slot number in the table. Regardless of the order in which they’re inserted, that slot will be scanned k times: once when the first item hashed to that slot is placed, and k-1 more times after that for the k-1 remaining items that hash there. No other items will touch that slot because the first slot in the table is empty and thus no wraparound can happen. Now, we can pretend that this slot is actually empty and that the k-1 remaining items actually hash to the next slot. Moreover, since linear probing insertion treats all items with the same hash code identically, which choice of k-1 items end up in the next slot does not matter. Therefore, across all insertion sequences, we’re left with k scans of the first slot, plus the work needed to place n items in the subsequent slots. None of those insertions will touch the first slot, so it’s as if we have n items to insert into a sequence of slots where the first and last slot are never touched. Our inductive hypothesis therefore tells us that the amount of work for these n items is the same regardless of insertion order, and so the total number of slots scanned does not depend on insertion order.)

## Quadratic Probing

Insertion order does matter in quadratic probing. Intuitively, if a collision occurs, the behavior of what happens next changes based on how far away from home an item is when the collision occurs.

Here’s a specific counterexample. Suppose items a, b, and c hash to slot 1, items p, q, and r hash to slot 2, and items w, x, and y hash to slot 4. Then if we insert the items in the order a, b, c, p, q, r, w, x, y, the following happens:

- a goes in 1 (1 slot touched)
- b tries 1 and goes in 2 (2 slots touched)
- c tries 1 and 2 and goes in 4 (3 slots touched)
- p tries 2 and goes in 3 (2 slots touched)
- q tries 2 and 3 and goes in 5 (3 slots touched)
- r tries 2, 3, and 5 and goes in 8 (4 slots touched)
- w tries 4 and 5 and goes in 7 (3 slots touched)
- x tries 4, 5, and 7 and goes in 10 (4 slots touched)
- z tries 4, 5, 7, and 10 and goes in 14 (5 slots touched)

A total of (1+2+3) + (2+3+4) + (3+4+5) = 6 + 9 + 12 = 27 slots are touched.

However, if you insert in the order a, p, w, b, q, x, c, r, y, the following happens:

- a goes in 1 (1 slot touched)
- p goes in 2 (1 slot touched)
- w goes in 4 (1 slot touched)
- b tries 1, 2, and 4 and goes in 7 (4 slots touched)
- q tries 2 and goes in slot 3 (2 slots touched)
- x tries 4 and goes in slot 5 (2 slots touched)
- c tries 1, 2, 4, and 7 and goes in slot 10 (5 slots touched)
- r tries slots 2, 3, 5 and goes in slot 8 (4 slots touched)
- y tries 4, 5, 7, and 10 and goes in slot 14 (5 slots touched)

Overall 1 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 5 + 4 + 5 = 25 slots are touched, less than the 27 from the first ordering.

## Double Hashing

Insertion order does matter in double hashing.

Let h1 and h2 be our hash functions. Because different items that have the same h1 value might not have the same h2 value, the effect of collisions does take in insertion order.

Here’s a specific counterexample: try inserting items whose (h1, h2) pairs are x = (1, 1), y = (1, 2), and z = (3, 1). If you insert x, then y, then z, the following happens:

- x is inserted in slot 1.
- y tries to go to slot 1 and fails. It’s then placed in slot 1 + 2 = 3.
- z tries to go in slot 3 and fails. It’s then placed in slot 3 + 1 = 4.

In total, five slots are scanned. However, with insertion order y, then x, then z, the following happens:

- y is inserted in slot 1.
- x tries to go in slot 1 and fails. It’s then placed in slot 1 + 1 = 2.
- z is inserted in slot 3.

In total, four slots are scanned.